# MongoDB replica set secondary node data loss

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have two `mongod` instances without replication each having same collection name but different data.Now initialized replication between them.Secondary machine copies all data from primary machine and looses it's original data.Can I recover original data present in secondary machine ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour with [MongoDB replica sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/): data from the primary is replicated to the secondaries.  When you add a server as a new secondary, it does an "initial sync" which copies data from the primary.  The replica sets are designed for failover and redundancy; your secondary nodes should have data consistent with the primary and their current replication lag.

If you have overwritten your previous database, your only option is to restore from a backup.

See also:

- [Backup and Restoration Strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/)
- [Replica Set Internals Part V: Initial Sync](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/06/26/replica-set-internals-part-v-initial-sync/)